# Parse push certificate testing

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push

I'm currently using a sashidio.io as my parse hosting, my current production cert is set to expire in a month so I wanted to get the new one up so there is no interruption.

I went ahead and generated a new push cert and uploaded but I do t see any way of testing this new cert out to make sure it's working?

My question is, does anyone know of a way to test your new cert out to make sure it will work with the current production? The only thing I can think of is to delete the old cert and test that way but my concern is, I can't download the old cert and I don't currently have the old cert so, if I delete the old cert and it does not work I'm hosed until I resubmit.

I know the certs should not be tied to the published cert of the app, just the bundle of but I have run into issues before where it does not work and I have had a few issues as of late with my main cert that required me to have to add it back to my key chain so I'm a little worried that it won't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Ad hoc certificate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955605/what-is-an-ad-hoc-certificate-for-ios-test-app-distribution

Comment: I don't think adhok would work because I would need to rebuild with that profile. Basically I want to test the new cert with the current production app. My cert that the app was signed with has expired so I want to make sure the cert will work with the current app.. the only way I can think of is to remove the prod cert and test new one but I don't have a backup of the current prod cert so if I remove it, and it does not work then I'm hosed until I can resubmit